# is my ERD and database structure is correct?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

My project is library system that has borrowed book and search for books for process. i don't know if my entity relationship diagram and database structure is 
correct

this is my database structure
http://postimg.org/image/vfilnibk9/

this is my ERD http://postimg.org/image/3q7gs7nc9/

Comment: You don't need student or book name in the Borrowed table. how do you know if a book is on loan and/or has been returned?

Comment: thanks i removed that is there any problem?